# PiCamera python : buff/cache memory keeps increasing

Tags: raspbian-stretch, python-3, picamera

I need to take a picture in each second in an infinite loop.
I've wrote 2 different python scripts: one with `camera.capture()` and another with `camera.capture_continuous()`

In both cases, I see the Buff/Cache memory keeps increasing until the maximum possible (after ~30 minutes).

When I stop the script, the memory stops increasing but doesn't decrease.
The only way I've found to decrease the buff/cache memory to a level similar to before launching the script is to remove all the created jpeg files....
Do you have an idea from where is the memory leak? Is it already known?

Here is my code:

```
with PiCamera() as camera:
    # Picamera object / objet Picamera
    camera.resolution = (cmd['camera_resolution'][0],cmd['camera_resolution'][1])
    camera.iso = cmd['camera_iso']
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        for i, image_filename in enumerate(camera.capture_continuous('image_{counter}.jpg', format='jpeg')):
        time.sleep(cmd['sleep_time'])
            if os.path.isfile(cmd['stopfile']):
                break
        camera.stop_preview()
        camera.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.stop_preview()
        camera.close()
        print ('Quit')
```

Comment: If I wrote a script which used more and more memory I'd assume I had an error in the script.

Comment: I've edited my post with my code. Do you see any error @joan?

Comment: I am not a Python guy but in C# this type of problem is handled by garbage collection. It seems like you are allocating thing to memory.. and then never releasing it. Hence it keeps growing and growing. Maybe this can help ?? https://www.digi.com/resources/documentation/digidocs/90001537/references/r_python_garbage_coll.htm

Comment: @ppumkin Thanks for your answer. Ok I agree with you about garbage collector. but I don't know how can free the memory with the usual piCamera syntax :
`with PiCamera() as camera:`

Comment: Well from what I just read about `with` it is like the `using` statement in C# - meaning once you are done with the code inside there... it should automatically dispose of it (letting GC know the memory can be free'd up) so maybe its not that `with` causing the problem. Again.. I dont know much about Python lifecycle and how it deals with stuff inside the `with` - in C# anything inside the `using` get marked disposed before the using is disposed. Maybe it is PiCamera not behaving properly and instead of getting disposed it hangs around doing something "magic" - who knows. play around a bit

Comment: Is there anybody that can reproduce the effect?

Comment: After discussing with Linux system specialists, it appears that having a Buff/Cache memory increase while writing files on the HDD is normal and doesn't impact the system performance. Is anybody can confirm it?